# Generate string like Q,R,S...AB where AB is last column in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a complex Google Sheet query that works great except when a Google Sheet doesn't have as many columns as I use in my formula.

Here's what the formula looks like now:

=sum(filter(query(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!$A$7:$23"),"select Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH where B='"&C2&"'",0),query(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!$A$7:$23"),"select Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH where B='PROJECT'",0) >=date(2017,1,1),query(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!$A$7:$23"),"select Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH where B='PROJECT'",0) <=date(2017,12,31)))

It works great. But the problem is I run it against many worksheets and some don't have e.g. column AG,AH and end at AF at which point I get an error.

So what I need is a way to generate the string Q,R,S....[Name of Last Column in Sheet] and then I can use that instead of my hard-coded Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with built-in functions:

1. On a helper sheet, let say you name it, `helper`, fill up range with letters `A` to `Z`, let say `A1:A26`
2. Let say that on `B1` you write the following formula:
   `=ArrayFormula({A1:A26;TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:A26)&A1:A26,,27)," ",",")),","))})` . This will create a list of column letter headers.
3. On each new worksheet use `columns(1:1)` to get the total number of columns.
4. To get your string of column headers, then you could use something like :

   - `JOIN(",",OFFSET(helper!B1,16,0,columns(1:1)-16))`
   - `QUERY(helper!B:B,"select B limit "&columns(1:1)-7&" offset 7")`

NOTE:

If you decide to have only one helper sheet and use it on several spreadsheets, then use

`QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(your_url,"helper!B:B"),"select Col1 limit "&columns(1:1)-7&" offset 7")`

Comment: Thanks, Ruben. I was trying to avoid adding data on the side or a helper sheet. I had previously realized that I could build a two-column table where I got the number of columns with Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1")) where A2 has worksheet name values and then do a lookup on a table where the first column is # of columns and second has strings like "Q", "Q, R", "Q, R, S" etc. In the end I am going with a solution that uses LEFT() to get the part of this long string that I need: Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC.

Comment: So once I know the columns in a sheet, I can get the right string for that sheet, and I just have to assume that no sheet will go out past BC, which I am pretty sure of. But I appreciate your solution and learned a lot from it. Thanks tons. Since you solved with formula as requested, I'll mark yours as a solution and close this out.

Comment: I doubt that anyone else will need this but here is the formula for how many characters to grab via LEFT() command: IF(B2>26,3*B2-59,2*B2-33) where the B column value contains the results of the Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1")) formula that gives the number of columns in any given worksheet.

Comment: So final formula for Row 2 was LEFT("Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY,AZ,BA,BB,BC
",2*Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1"))-33+IF(Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1"))>26,Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1"))-26,0))

Comment: @user1883779: Please consider to post your solution as a response.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments above, final formula was:

LEFT("Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,A‌​L,AM,AN,AO,AP,AQ,AR,‌​AS,AT,AU,AV,AW,AX,AY‌​,AZ,BA,BB,BC ",2*Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"!1:1"))-33+IF(Columns(INDIRECT(A2&"‌​!1:1"))>26,Columns(I‌​NDIRECT(A2&"!1:1"))-‌​26,0))

where column A contains the list of worksheets (tabs) in the Google Sheet. Put this in B2, and then copied it down. I am not marking this as the correct answer since others gave a correct formula-based answer but this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with script. Without seeing you spreadsheet, it is hard to know exactly what you need, but this should be close. I get the variables from Sheet1 and return the formula to Sheet1. Adjust the sheet name to fit your needs. This will look at your data sheets based on the variable sheet name determine the last column. Determine the column letters and build the string the query needs. It then sets the new query formula. I added a menu to run it from.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Create Data', [ 
      { name: 'Run', functionName: 'formula' },
      ]);  
}
function formula(){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1") //sheet where variables are
  var sheet=s.getRange("A2").getValue()//variable sheet name
  var sel=makeString(sheet) //get the select string of column letters
  //Create formula and return to Sheet1 A3
  var f= s.getRange("A3").setFormula('=sum(filter(query(INDIRECT("\'" & A2 & "\'!$A$7:$23"),"select '+sel+' where B=\'"&C2&"\'",0),query(INDIRECT("\'" & A2 & "\'!$A$7:$23"),"select '+sel+' where B=\'PROJECT\'",0) >=date(2017,1,1),query(INDIRECT("\'" & A2 & "\'!$A$7:$23"),"select '+sel+' where B=\'PROJECT\'",0) <=date(2017,12,31)))')
   }
function makeString(sht){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName(sht)
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  var rng=s.getRange(1, 17, 1, lc).getValues()
  var str=''
  var ltr=[]
    for(var i=17;i<rng[0].length+1;i++){
   ltr[i]= columnToLetter(i)
    str=ltr.join(',')
  }
  var str1=str.substr(17)
  return str1
}
function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks tons for this. It's very helpful and I can use it on another project. For this, I'm trying to do with just formulas.